# getting undefined while printing the function value from an object

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I am new to JavaScript and learning Objects in JavaScript  ,
while i was printing a function value from an object the value gets printed along with a undefined value.

I was just trying to concatenate two string in a function and printing it.
I am not getting any undefined value if I just try to concatenate the string with console.log
but the issue arises when I try to concatenate through a function in a object.

```
let user = {
    firstname:'faiz',
    lastname:'mohammed',
    fun : function()  {
        let full_name = (this.firstname + " " + this.lastname);
        console.log(full_name);
        },

}


console.log(user.fun());
```

the output is :

```
PS C:\Users\faizk\OneDrive\Desktop\WEBDEV\JS> node objects.js
faiz mohammed
undefined
PS C:\Users\faizk\OneDrive\Desktop\WEBDEV\JS>
```

when I just console log it I am not getting any undefined values :

```
console.log(user.firstname + " " + user.lastname);
```

output:

```
PS C:\Users\faizk\OneDrive\Desktop\WEBDEV\JS> node objects.js
faiz mohammed
PS C:\Users\faizk\OneDrive\Desktop\WEBDEV\JS>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `fun` function doesn't return anything so `console.log(user.fun())` prints `undefined`

Either return something:

```
function()  {
  let full_name = (this.firstname + " " + this.lastname);
  return full_name
},

console.log(user.fun());
```

or don't use `console.log`

```
function()  {
  let full_name = (this.firstname + " " + this.lastname);
  console.log(full_name);
},

user.fun();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the function is a `void` function ( don't `return` any thing ) and any `void` function will return `undefined`

```js
let user = {
    firstname:'faiz',
    lastname:'mohammed',
    fun : function()  {
        let full_name = (this.firstname + " " + this.lastname);
        console.log(full_name); // faiz mohamed
        // the function doesn't return anything, which equal to "return undefined"
    },

}


console.log(user.fun()); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling `console.log(user.fun())`. `user.fun()` prints a line with `console.log()`. This is where the first line of output comes from.

`user.fun()` does not return any value, so the return value is `undefined`. `console.log(user.fun())` prints the output of `user.fun()`, which is `undefined`. This is where the second line comes from.

To fix this, just change your last line of code from

```
console.log(user.fun())
```

to

```
user.fun()
```